# Sonata admin doesn't recognize choices option

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to implement a filter that will select one of the following statusses:

```
public const OPEN                  = 'open';
public const READY_FOR_EXECUTION   = 'ready_for_execution';
public const IN_PROGRESS           = 'in_progress';
public const PAYOUT                = 'payout';
public const ARCHIVED              = 'archived';
```

I tried to implement the filter as follows:

```
$filter->add('type', 'doctrine_orm_choice', ['label' => 'Status'], null, ['choices' => Status::getValues()])
```

This is a way I found on Stackoverflow. However, whenever I execute the code, Symfony throws a 500 server error:

```
The option "choices" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "field_wrapper_attr", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "horizontal_input_wrapper_class", "horizontal_label_class", "horizontal_label_offset_class", "inherit_data", "input_wrapper_attr", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_raw", "label_render", "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "sonata_admin", "sonata_field_description", "sonata_help", "tooltip", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
```

Obviously this approach doesn't work, and the documentation isn't very clear about this either. Can someone please explain to me how to create a filter that'll let a user select one of the 5 values through a html select or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific ChoiceType Field, instead of the FormType Field you use.
You can play with multiple and expanded to use alternatively checkboxes, radio buttons, or select.
See the doc:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html
Example:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('_', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => [
            'yes' => true,
            'no' => false,
            'maybe' => null,
            ],
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'checkbox-inline'),
))
```

**EDIT:**

I gave you symfony based information. Maybe it doesn't work with Sonata. But the Sonata doc says to do it this way:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;

final class PageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('multiChoices', ChoiceType::class, [
                'multiple' => true,
                'sortable' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Source:https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#symfonycomponentformextensioncoretypechoicetype

Comment: This returns: `Too few arguments to function Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\ChoiceType::__construct(), 0 passed in /projects/youngones/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Filter/FilterFactory.php on line 53 and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: Im an idiot, you were using a different ChoiceType class _facepalm_